# Get differences between Array and ActiveRecord thousands of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get deltas of additions, deletions, and updates between a csv data with about 500,000 records in comparison to an ActiveRecord.

iden being the identifier for their differences

ex. csv_data

```
[{
 iden: 1, group_num: 111 
}, 
{
 iden: 2, group_num: 222
}, 
{
 iden: 3, group_num: 333
}, 
{
 iden: 4, group_num: 444
}]
```

ex. ActiveRecordData

```
[{
 iden: 2, group_num: 222
}, 
{
 iden: 3, group_num: 333
}, 
{
 iden: 4, group_num: 999
}, 
{
 iden: 5, group_num: 555
}]
```

As a result I would want to get

an array of additions

```
[{
 iden: 5, group_num: 555
}]
```

an array of removals

```
[{
 iden: 1, group_num: 111 
}]
```

an array of updates

```
[{
 iden: 4, group_num: 999
}]
```

I tried iterating through each to get the particular deltas but it's taking hours for large hundred thousand data sets. How would I better optimize this?

```
    additions = []
    updates = []
    csv_data.each_slice(1000).map do |chunk|
      chunk.map { |csv_item|
        active_record = ActiveRecordData.where(iden: csv_item[:iden])
        if !active_record.exists?
          additions << active_record
        elsif active_record.first.group_num != csv_item[:group_num]
          updates << active_record
        end
      }
    end
    deletions = ActiveRecordData.all.select{|active_record| !csv_data.any?{|csv_item| csv_item[:iden] == active_record.iden}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by addressing these issues:

- Multiple queries for every item
- Loading data you don't use
- Instantiating ActiveRecord models unnecessarily

```rb
csv_data.each_slice(1000).map do |chunk|
  records = ActiveRecordData
              .where(iden: chunk.map(&:iden))
              .pluck(:iden, :group_num)

  additions += chunk.reject do |row|
    records.find { |record| record.iden == row.iden }
  end

  updates += chunk.select do |row|
    record = records.find { |record| record.iden == row.iden }
    record.group_num != row.group_num
  end
end
```

Finally, you likely need to go about your `deletions` in a different way. If your `iden` values are numeric and relatively sequential, one low-hanging approach is to fetch just `iden` values within a range (e.g. `where(iden: 1..100_000).pluck(:iden)`), then loop through your data to identify and add deleted records to a `deletions` buffer before moving on to the next batch.

Comment: It wasn't explicitly stated, but judging from the example of the expected output, it seems that OP wants to do a diff in the _opposite direction_, i.e. what changes need to be made to CSV data to make it match DB data. That would make it much more difficult, essentially you'd need to ask the DB to give you "everything not in CSV" without specifying the CSV in the query since it contains 0.5M entries. And you can't do it in chunks, because if something in not in the current chunk it may be in some next one.

Comment: Thanks @BorisB. something I did not explicitly state but I'm trying to get whats not in the ActiveRecord but was added to the CSV data. Not sure how I can go about it without calling to many queries.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation on the solution and pointing out what issues I had within my code @coreyward!

Comment: @KamSami If you do want to do what Boris B. suggests, you can largely just approach this from the other direction and use [`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) to iterate through all rows in the table in batches.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a temporary table with a primary key over `ident` and the load the CSV data into the table using bulk inserts in chunks. Once there it would be trivial (and very fast) to get the diff of two tables:

`SELECT table_a.ident, table_a.group_num FROM table_a WHERE table_a.ident NOT IN (SELECT table_b.ident FROM table_b)`

`SELECT table_b.ident, table_b.group_num FROM table_b WHERE table_b.ident NOT IN (SELECT table_a.ident FROM table_a)`

`SELECT table_a.ident, table_a.group_num INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.ident = table_b.ident AND table_a.group_num <> table_b.group_num`